# Beginner user registration and login program

Tags: c++, beginner, console

I'm new to coding and C++, this is one of my first pieces of "software". Could anyone give me some constructive criticism?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool IsLoggedIn()
{
    string user, pass, un, pw;
    cout << "Username: " << endl;
    cin >> user;
    cout << "Password: " << endl;
    cin >> pass;

    ifstream read(user + ".txt");
    getline(read, un);
    getline(read, pw);

    if (un == user && pw == pass)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}

inline bool does_file_exist(const string& name)
{
    ifstream filename(name +".txt");
    if(!filename)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

int main()
{
    system("clear");

    int input;
    cout << "(1) Create Account \n" << "(2) Log in \n"<< "(3) Change password" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    if (input == 1 || input == 2 || input == 3)
    {
        if (input == 1)
        {
            system("clear");

            string user, pass;

            cout << "Create Account \n" << endl;
            cout << "Username: " << endl;
            cin >> user;

            if (does_file_exist(user))
            {
                cout << "Username already registered \n" << "Press enter to retry...";
                cin.ignore();
                cin.get();
                main();
            }

            cout << "Password: " << endl;
            cin >> pass;

            ofstream file;
            file.open(user + ".txt");
            file << user << endl << pass;
            file.close();

            main();
        }

        else if (input == 2)
        {
            system("clear");

            cout << "Log In \n" << endl;

            bool status = IsLoggedIn();

            if (!status)
            {
                cout << "Incorrect username or password!" << endl << "Press enter to retry...";
                cin.ignore();
                cin.get();
                main();
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Successfully logged in!" << endl;
                cin.get();
                return 1;
            }

        }

        else if (input == 3)
        {
            system("clear");

            string user, pass;

            cout << "Change password \n" << endl;
            cout << "Username: " << endl;
            cin >> user;
            if (does_file_exist(user))
            {
                cout << "New Password: " << endl;
                cin >> pass;

                ofstream file;
                file.open(user + ".txt");
                file << user << endl << pass;
                file.close();

            main();
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Username not registered \n" << "Press enter to retry...";
                cin.ignore();
                cin.get();
                main();
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        system("clear");
        cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
        main();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

***Not a full review, but too long for a comment***

I'm not a `C++` developer, but there are a few common foundational programming mistakes that you've made that I saw:

- `using namespace std` is a bad practice. This imports the entirety of the namespace into the current namespace, which can cause a multitude of problems. [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice/) is an article that explains the possible problems, going more in-depth than I could ever. *Note: I didn't change anything that would require `std::` at the beginning by removing the namespace, merely for the fact that I don't have the time right now. That can be a good exercise for you :).
- Instead of `return true; } else { return false; }`, simply return the expression you're evaluating. For example in your code, `return (un == user && pw == pass)`.
- When a user enters an already existing username/incorrect username or password/username not registered, you call `main()` again. This can fill the stack pretty quickly with these recursive calls. What if a user keeps making mistakes? Then you have tens or even *hundreds* of `main` calls in the stack. Not good. You can wrap all the code in `main` in a `while` loop. If a user makes a mistake, simply do nothing and let the loop reset. If a user makes a valid choice, do what you need to do, then `break`. *Note: Didn't implement this either because of time, this one is for you :)*.

***Barely changed but still changed code***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

//ADD "std::" TO ALL THINGS THAT COME FROM STD NAMESPACE

bool IsLoggedIn()
{
    string user, pass, un, pw;
    cout << "Username: " << std::endl;
    cin >> user;
    cout << "Password: " << endl;
    cin >> pass;

    ifstream read(user + ".txt");
    getline(read, un);
    getline(read, pw);

    return (un == user && pw == pass);

}

inline bool does_file_exist(const string& name)
{
    ifstream filename(name +".txt");

    return filename;

}

int main()
{
    system("clear");

    int input;
    cout << "(1) Create Account \n" << "(2) Log in \n"<< "(3) Change password" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    if (input == 1 || input == 2 || input == 3)
    {
        if (input == 1)
        {
            system("clear");

            string user, pass;

            cout << "Create Account \n" << endl;
            cout << "Username: " << endl;
            cin >> user;

            if (does_file_exist(user))
            {
                cout << "Username already registered \n" << "Press enter to retry...";
                cin.ignore();
                cin.get();
                main();
            }

            cout << "Password: " << endl;
            cin >> pass;

            ofstream file;
            file.open(user + ".txt");
            file << user << endl << pass;
            file.close();

            main();
        }

        else if (input == 2)
        {
            system("clear");

            cout << "Log In \n" << endl;

            bool status = IsLoggedIn();

            if (!status)
            {
                cout << "Incorrect username or password!" << endl << "Press enter to retry...";
                cin.ignore();
                cin.get();
                main();
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Successfully logged in!" << endl;
                cin.get();
                return 1;
            }

        }

        else if (input == 3)
        {
            system("clear");

            string user, pass;

            cout << "Change password \n" << endl;
            cout << "Username: " << endl;
            cin >> user;
            if (does_file_exist(user))
            {
                cout << "New Password: " << endl;
                cin >> pass;

                ofstream file;
                file.open(user + ".txt");
                file << user << endl << pass;
                file.close();

            main();
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Username not registered \n" << "Press enter to retry...";
                cin.ignore();
                cin.get();
                main();
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        system("clear");
        cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
        main();
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to your recursion point. The function `main()` is special and recursive calls are not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

- Never ever recurse into `main`. You may get away with it in C; in C++ it would <strike>surely wake dragons</strike> [cause undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2128727/3403834). Use loops.
- There is no need to validate input separately.

  ```
      if (input == 1) {
          ....
      } else if (input == 2) {
          ....
      } else if (input == 3) {
          ....
      } else {
          std::cout << "Invalid input\n";
      }
  ```

  is sufficient. As a side note, instead of cascading `if`s, consider a `switch` statement.
- Avoid magic numbers. Define few symbolic constants, e.g.

  ```
  static const int Register = 1;
  // etc
  ```

  and use them.
- DRY.

  First of all, `system("clear")` is called in all branches. Call it once. As a side note, avoid calling it at all. It may not be present in a target system.

  Second, the repeated code such as

  ```
      ofstream file;
      file.open(user + ".txt");
      file << user << endl << pass;
      file.close();
  ```

  shall be factored into a function.
- `does_file_exist` does not have a right to exist. It introduces a time-to-check/time-to-use race condition. Just open a file and see if it opened successfully. For example,

  ```
      ofstream file(user + ".txt");
      if (file) {
          proceed();
      } else {
          report_error();
      }
  ```

  As a side note,

  ```
      if (!filename) {
          return false;
      } else {
          return true;
      }
  ```

  is a very long way to say

  ```
      return filename;
  ```

  Ditto for `IsLoggedIn`.
- Be consistent with the return values. Some of the branches do return, some does not. As yet another side note, traditionally returning 0 means success.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all of the other reviews but I would recommend you to use a a switch statement instead of long if-elses.

```
switch(input){
case 1:
// do stuff
break;
case 2:
// do other stuff
break;
case 3:
// do other stuff
break;
default:
// Invalid input
break;
}
```

In my opinion this increases readability and provides a good way of checking states and catching invalid inputs.

To clear the console screen your are using `system("clear")` which is okay, but not good practise because its OS-specific. For Unix based systems like MacOS and Linux this would cause undefined behaviour or simply do nothing. A workaround that is portable and can be used on *NIX platforms is simply using ANSI escape characters:

```
void clear() {
    // CSI[2J clears screen, CSI[H moves the cursor to top-left corner
    std::cout << "\x1B[2J\x1B[H";
}
```

(Taken from User Cat Plus Plus from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486289/how-can-i-clear-console)

Now you have to options, either determine which OS the program runs or just trying both `system(clear)` and `clear()`.